# Shell script that iterates through a sql "delete" statement

Tags: mysql, shell

I need a shell script that deletes 1000 rows from a massive database until **there is no more rows left**

It is very simple, but i am very weak in shell scripting, and the many tutorials online offer extremely similar, but different nuances in syntax

UPDATE:

- Would it be possible to get some sample code?
- I need to delete 1000 rows at a time
- I have 120 Million rows to delete in total, and deleting them all at once will lock up the DB

Comment: Do you need a shell script that runs an SQL statement, or are you planning on using the shell script for logic?

Comment: Is it not possible to just write an SQL query that deletes all 1000 rows?

Comment: Are you just trying to erase the table?

Comment: What is the question? How to write a shell script or how to execute a mysql-query from a shell script or how to delete rows?

Comment: Updated again - i need to delete 1000 at a time because i have 120M rows in total, and i need the DB to be up and running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call the mysql command line tool:

```
mysql -u username -p password < statements.txt
```

or

```
echo "your statement here" | mysql -u username -p password
```

in statements.txt put:

```
delete from `table` limit 1000;
```

although i do not understand why you only want to delete 1k at a time

a full script for `sh` would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'DELETE FROM `table` LIMIT 1000;' | mysql -u username -p password
```

Comment: Thanks knittl! I was wondering more about how i can construct the loop? I just could not get the full script to work.

I have 120 Million rows to delete in total, and deleting them all at once will lock up the DB

Comment: @ming: have you considered using `TRUNCATE TABLE`? it's much faster than using the delete statement, when you have to delete all rows from a table

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this using just mysql:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -D <database> -u <user> -p<password> -e 'DELETE FROM <table> WHERE <condition> LIMIT 10000;'
```

**-e** - accepts a query as an argument

Answer (score 1):

Just hope my script maybe help someone who search similar questions

```
#!/bin/sh
# mysql_delta_del.sh 
# -----------------------------

db_user="root"
db_host="127.0.0.1"
db_passwd="yourpass"
db="yourdb"
db_table="mytable"
keep_records=10000000
## start id, you can change according your db
start_id=31000000

# mysql bin's path
MYSQL="$(which mysql)"


maxid=`$MYSQL -u $db_user -h $db_host -p$db_passwd $db -e 'select max(id) from $db_table'`

maxid=`echo $maxid |cut -d" " -f2`

#keep last 10 million records
delto=`echo $maxid - $keep_records  |bc`

echo "target id: $delto"


i=$start_id 
while [ $i -lt $delto ]
do
 echo "delete to $i "

 echo "DELETE FROM $db_table where id<$i LIMIT 1000 " | mysql -u $db_user -p$db_passwd -h $db_host $db
 true $(( i=i+1000 ))

done
```